# Issues Reloading Table Cell After Updating Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am using Firestore and Firebase storage with my app. I am having an issue, I am downloading the cell content, then downloading images and inserting them into the row. However, the images are not showing unless you click on a row, forcing it to refresh. How do I automatically reload the content after downloading the image? I tried using the code snippet below, but it froze the app and caused the CPU utilization to max out. So I'm not sure if I placed it in the wrong spot, or if I should be using a different technique.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.inventoryTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is an overview of the process of how my app works:

1. Call "downloadAssetList" and download the table content, which includes URL's to download the correct images.
2. Call "setInventoryCell" which downloads the images and assigns it to the UIImageView in the cell

Below is an image hopefully better showing the issue.

[image]

InventoryViewController.swift

```
//
//  InventoryViewController.swift
//  ItemizePro
//
//  Created by Tyler Wasick on 5/18/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tyler Wasick. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class InventoryViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var inventoryTableView: UITableView!
    
    var assetList = [Asset]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // Configure the tableview delegate and data source
        inventoryTableView.delegate = self
        inventoryTableView.dataSource = self
        
        // Download asset list
        FirebaseDB.downloadAssetList { (list) in
            self.assetList = list
            self.inventoryTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Functions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }

}

extension InventoryViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(assetList.count)
        return assetList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Format date field
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
                
        // Set the cell with asset data
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboards.TableViewCell.inventoryCellID) as! InventoryListView
        
        // Get the asset for that rown
        let cellAsset = assetList[indexPath.row]
        
        // Set the cell details
        cell.setInventoryCell(cellAsset)

        // Return the row
        return cell
    }
}
```

InventoryListView.swift

```
//
//  InventoryListView.swift
//  ItemizePro
//
//  Created by Tyler Wasick on 7/20/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tyler Wasick. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class InventoryListView: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var assetImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var itemText: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var roomLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var roomText: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var purchasedLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var purchasedText: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    // Print inventory cell
    func setInventoryCell(_ inventoryAsset:Asset) {
        
        // TODO: Break this out into its own function that uses a trailing closure¥
        // Download an image
        if inventoryAsset.assetImageURL?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) != "" || inventoryAsset.assetImageURL != nil {
            
            // Create a reference to the storage service
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            
            // Create a reference to the storage service
            let pathRef = storage.reference(forURL: inventoryAsset.assetImageURL!)
            
            // Download the URL data
            pathRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, err) in
                
                // Check to see if an error has occured
                if let err = err {
                    
                    // An error has occured
                    print(err)
                } else {
                    
                    // Download image data
                    let assetImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                    
                    // Assign image to asset
                    inventoryAsset.assetImage = assetImage
                    
                    // Set the asset image
                    if let image = inventoryAsset.assetImage {
                        self.imageView?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
            //closure()
        }
        
        // Set date to be displayed
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM-yyyy"
        
        // Set prototype cell fields
        // Set "asset" label
        if let name = inventoryAsset.name {
            itemText.text = name
        } else {
            itemText.text = ""
        }
        
        // Set "room" label
        if let room = inventoryAsset.room {
            roomText.text = room
        } else {
            roomText.text = ""
        }
        
        // Set "purchased" label
        if let date = inventoryAsset.datePurchased {
            purchasedText.text = formatter.string(from: date)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You run the code to download the image in the cell. Don't do that. Cells are reused and can be deallocated immediately. Put the logic in the controller or the model.

Comment: You can initiate a download in a cell, but you do need to handle reuse. If you are going to do that I would strongly suggest you look at SDWebImage or Kingfisher.  From the description of your problem it sounds like you are causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with firebase storage and I'm using Kingfisher for the download and caching of images. Highly recommend you try it out too. Here is how I do it:

```
let imageRef = Storage.storage().child("path/to/resource")
imageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
    guard let downloadedURL = url else {
        // handle error
        return
    }

    imageView.kf.setImage(with: downloadedURL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fire base why not use fire base UI , it gives you package called SDWebImage which gives you multiple options like progressive loading and high priority loading and also various options using closures. It’s one line to implement too, takes URL as parameter.
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

It provides native caching. So no more lines to set cache either. One line and it solves everything

Answer (score 0):

Image display on the table cell can be tricky since the cells are reused and also sometimes the image size may be too big so they can take time to download, having said that I recommend using SDWebImage which takes care of the image download more elegantly.

Link: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage